# How create a drop down list box using data from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help in populating a drop down down list from a mysql table. I'm new to php and I am having a hard time. Here's my code and I know it's wrong, I just don't know where.

My current output is just a drop down box with nothing inside it.

My expected output is that it would show the driver's name from the mysql table.

```
<?php
$Hehe = $mydb->getALL('SELECT drivername FROM driver;'); //select from all users
?>
<select name=mydriver value=''>Driver Name</option> // list box select command
<?php
foreach($Hehe as $hehe){//Array or records stored in $row
?>
<option name = "mydriver"><?phpecho $Hehe['drivername']?></option>

</select>
<?php
}
?>
```

the getALL function:

```
function getAll($query) {
    $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $ret = $result->execute();
    if (!$ret) {
   echo 'PDO::errorInfo():';
   echo '<br />';
   echo 'error SQL: '.$query;
   die();
}
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$reponse = $result->fetchAll();

return $reponse;
}
```

Comment: *it's wrong, i just don't know where.* is not a right description of your problem. Please tell us which part of the code is not working, your expected Vs. current output etc.

Comment: my current output is just a drop down box with nothing inside it. My expected output is that it would show the drivers name from the mysql table.

Comment: What this custom `getALL` method does? Did you check whether it returns any array or not? Do `var_dump($Hehe);` and see what you have there. And please use some meaningful variable names, `$Hehe` and `$hehe` make no sense.

Comment: I sent an answer to what the getALL method does. I'm really new to PHP and MYSQL. Any help would be accepted.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong array to get the *drivername*. It should be `$hehe['drivername']`, not `$Hehe['drivername']`. Like I said, use some meaningful variable names in your code, it would be easy for you track down the error. Also `</select>` should be outside of `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
    $Hehe = $mydb->getALL('SELECT drivername FROM driver;'); //select from all users
    ?>
    <select name="mydriver">Driver Name</option> // list box select command
        <?php
        foreach($Hehe as $hehe){//Array or records stored in $row
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $hehe['drivername']; ?>"><?php echo $hehe['drivername']; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

---

**Sidenote:** Always turn on error reporting, add these two statements `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`at the very top of your PHP scripts to debug any syntax related issues.

Comment: @MacarauneSalad If this answer helped you in any way, please consider "upvoting" it, and if it solved the issue, please also "checkmark" it as the "accepted answer".  Our community thrives on these simple acts of appreciation.  It also helps anyone connected to the web to find useful answers to *their* programming questions.  Thanks!